# JQuery Autocomplete will not allow selection from dropdown IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code works on the I.E. 9, Chrome, and Safari, but numerous people are having problems with older versions of Internet Explorer and current version of Firefox. It displays the drop down selections as it is supposed to but will not allow the users to click a selection. Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js"></script>

<link type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
<style>
.ui-autocomplete-loading { background: white url('images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif') right center no-repeat; }
</style>
<script>
$(function() {
    function log( message ) {
        $( "<div/>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#inputString" );
        $( "#inputString" ).scrollTop( 0 );
        showCar(message);
    }

    $( "#inputString" ).autocomplete({
        source: "ajax/search.php",
        minLength: 1,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            log( ui.item ?
                "Selected: " + ui.item.value :
                "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );

        }

    });


});
</script>
```

Using the development tools, it shows up this error in the console: SCRIPT65535: Unexpected call to method or property access. 
jquery-1.6.2.js, line 5609 character 5

which points to this:

```
prepend: function() {
    return this.domManip(arguments, true, function( elem ) {
        if ( this.nodeType === 1 ) {
            this.insertBefore( elem, this.firstChild );
        }
    });
},
```

**EDIT**
Now its throwing an error saying: SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'prepend' 
jquery-1.6.2.js, line 5975 character 4

which is :

```
jQuery.each({
appendTo: "append",
prependTo: "prepend",
insertBefore: "before",
insertAfter: "after",
replaceAll: "replaceWith"
}, function( name, original ) {
jQuery.fn[ name ] = function( selector ) {
    var ret = [],
        insert = jQuery( selector ),
        parent = this.length === 1 && this[0].parentNode;

    if ( parent && parent.nodeType === 11 && parent.childNodes.length === 1 && insert.length === 1 ) {
        insert[ original ]( this[0] );
        return this;

    } else {
        for ( var i = 0, l = insert.length; i < l; i++ ) {
            var elems = (i > 0 ? this.clone(true) : this).get();
            jQuery( insert[i] )[ original ]( elems );
            ret = ret.concat( elems );
        }

        return this.pushStack( ret, name, insert.selector );
    }
};
});
```

Line 5974 is the top line in this section:

```
if ( parent && parent.nodeType === 11 && parent.childNodes.length === 1 && insert.length === 1 ) {
        insert[ original ]( this[0] );
        return this;

    }
```

Comment: What type of data is search.php returning?

Comment: Its returning JSON via json_encode()

Comment: Any ideas? I need to get this fixed by tonight and am so stressed

Comment: Which version of jQuery UI are you using?  I see you're using jQuery 1.6.2.  We should make sure your version of jQuery UI is compatible with jQuery 1.6.2.

Comment: OK, so I downloaded all the new UI files used and now the autocomplete is throwing the same error and not working on all browsers.... using 1.8.17 ui. The error showing in chrome is Object [object Object] has no method 'prepend'

Comment: Can you post a sample of what your search.php file returns? Ideally a jsFiddle would be helpful. Also, what is"showCar" and why not remove your log function and just console.log or alert() the selected value?

Comment: @j08691 [{"id":"31","value":"Barber Shops"}] I dont know how to use jsFiddle to simulate ajax requests.

Comment: @j08691 showCar is another function called using the selected row in autocomplete. It does another ajax request, I tried deleting the call to this function and does not affect the error

Comment: @j08691 show me another way to implement using console.log and I will try. The appendTo function in log is the problem anyway.

Comment: What is the line `$( "<div/>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#inputString" );` supposed to do?

Comment: @j08691 I guess its there to shit on my webpage. I deleted it and it works now.

Comment: Wow, all that time spent trying to narrow this down and all I got was a chuckle out of your reply. :(

Comment: haha, answer it so I can give you a 1 up and check mark. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use compilation for your project, you might consider to install and add at the top of your entry point - file

```
import 'core-js'
```

At the moment [core-js polyfill library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js) is the easiest way to make Cross Browser Support